# check condition in select option tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and html, I am using dropdown with some dynamic values using `ng-repeat`. This is my code:

```
<select ng-model="device.data.caller_id.emergency.number" 
        tooltip-html-unsafe="Define the Caller ID Number of this Device for Emergency Calls."     
        class="form-control input-default" 
        id="caller_id_number_emergency">
  <option value="" id="">- No Number -</option>
  <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.numbers" 
            value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

And if the user selects any option it should check some condition,and if the result is `true` then do nothing and if the result is `false` then it should open new pop up.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `select` attribute `ng-change`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can **trigger a function** which is define in controller by using `ng-change` directive

```
  <select ng-model="device.data.caller_id.emergency.number" id="caller_id_number_emergency" ng-change="checkCondtition(device.data.caller_id.emergency.number)">
    <option value="" id="">- No Number -</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.numbers" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
  </select>
```

here I send selected value to function as parameter and there you can define your business...

here is a example [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qixzgcLWWLNbwVjovWXW?p=preview)...

Answer (score 0):

change your code

class="form-control input-default" 
        id="caller_id_number_emergency">
  - No Number -
  {{key}}
 
to

```
<select ng-model="selectdata" 
        tooltip-html-unsafe="Define the Caller ID Number of this Device for Emergency Calls."     
        class="form-control input-default" 
        id="caller_id_number_emergency" ng-options=""data.number in data>
  <option value="" id="">- No Number -</option>
</select>
```

now this selectdata model return selected value